# Check if a list of values are plus or minus 1 of each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of values `scores = [80,90,50,60,70]`

Trying to write an all statement to determine if the values are +/- 2 of each other.

I've figured out how to code if they are +/- 2 of some value say 82, but not sure if it is even possible to do +/- 2 of each other.

I am not sure where to start the below is how I would write it if I am getting +/- 2 of 82

```
all(79 < x < 84 for x in scores)
```

Comment: you want to know if there are a semi-continuos list? as in there are not two continuos integer that are not in the list?
[1,2,3,5,4] is True
[1,2,2,5,6] is False because 2 < 5-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to figure out if *all* of the values are within a range with some particular magnitude, take the difference of the `min` and `max`.  For example, given a bunch of numbers that are all within +/- 2 of 82:

```
>>> nums = [80, 82, 84, 83, 81]
```

we can subtract the `min` from the `max` to see that the upper bound is only 4 away from the lower bound:

```
>>> max(nums) - min(nums)
4
```

That means that all the numbers are within 4 of each other (since by definition the min and max are the furthest apart from each other), and all the numbers are within 2 (i.e. half of 4) of some number in the middle (in this case 82).

If you already know the number in question (82) and are interested in how far the other numbers are from that specific number, take the difference from that number:

```
>>> max(nums) - 82
2
>>> min(nums) - 82
-2
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I am looking for.  I am no math genius and I would have probably never figured this out.  This probably doesn't take a math genius to figure out but you are a savior.  Thanks.  Also this makes sense to me as well.